# Bug in Mono !? WebRequest to a HTTPS resource with proxy fails to work

Tags: c#, xamarin, mono, xamarin.android

I have a proxy(Fiddler) setup and I created an Android app on Windows 10 x64 with latest Xamarin stable as of today, with the following code:

```
        IWebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("http://192.168.1.100:8888/");
        proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("johndoe", "1234567890");
        WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = proxy;

        var req = WebRequest.CreateHttp("https://www.google.com");
        req.GetResponse();
```

throws exception:

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> System.Net.WebException: Error: Success

If I change the request to non-secure URL: `http://www.google.com` **it works fine!**

I've found something which looks similar, not sure, here:

https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3969

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=19594

Is there a workaround?

**If I put same C# code in a console app, it works with both HTTPS and HTTP URLS so Fiddler is not an issue!**

I even tried to set the proxy authorization header like this, but it didn't work:

```
req.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ProxyAuthorization, "Basic am9obmRvZToxMjM0NTY3ODkw");
```

Comment: The latest **stable** release includes **Mono 4.6.2.16**, you are looking for **Mono 4.8+** and that is available in the **alpha channel**

Comment: I also experienced this issue, and it look like problems with Fiddler itself, not with Mono.

Comment: @SushiHangover Thanks. I do not wish to switch to alpha channel. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: @YuryGlushkov No, it's not a problem with Fiddler. It works fine if I run same code in a console C# app. This is a problem which has been acknowledge in Bugzilla, you can see it in the link I posted

Comment: @DonBox if your bug is fixed in the alpha channel, there's no other way to solve your problem; it's a bug and you got a way to get the bugfix, there's no workaround