# C# WebProxy with credentials

Tags: c#, proxy, webrequest

I want to make requests through proxy with authentication, but getting  Error: Success.
If I don't use proxy, requests works fine. Proxy data is correct, I've tested it with curl.
Requests fails only with https.

```cs
var p = new WebProxy(ProxyUrl, ProxyPort)
{
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ProxyUsername, ProxyPassword)
};

var req = WebRequest.Create("https://api.ipify.org/?format=json");
req.Proxy = p;
req.GetResponse();
```

Error log:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.Net.WebException: Error: Success
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00064] in <bd46d4d4f7964dfa9beea098499ab597>:0 
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse () [0x0000e] in <bd46d4d4f7964dfa9beea098499ab597>:0 

...

Process finished with exit code 1.
```

Console App .net v4.6.1

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know the answer, but I'm pretty sure it's something deeper than Flurl. If you can repro with a "raw" HttpClient/Handler and post a question in that context, someone might be able to help. Be sure and provide details/tags about the platform you're running on. Is it Mono by chance? See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41520759/62600) is relevant.

Comment: @ToddMenier thx for comment. I updated question with WebRequest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in Mono, I had version 4.6.2.
So I installed latest version(5.20.1.19) from https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/ and the problem is gone.